# ignore missing credentials jenkins DSL

Tags: groovy, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

How to enable *Ignore missing credential* option under ssh-agent using DSL Groovy script?
I have tried using `ignoreMissingCredentials = true`, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that:

```
wrappers {
   sshAgentBuildWrapper {
      ignoreMissing(true)
   }
}
```

might be what are you looking for.

Comment: Error: No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.wrapper.WrapperContext.ignoreMissing() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]

Comment: @devops, have you configured the while context? Please have a look at the edited question.